# esmock with sinon and checking if a function is calledOnce

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

I'm trying to update a project to use import / export and that's lead me to using esmock for mocking responses in my unit tests.  I used to have this code which I could then check with calledOnce & this worked when using require and sinon.stub().

`mapCountAllTeams = sinon.stub(adminJS, 'mapCountAllTeams').returns(false);`

Now I've updated it to esmock like this because of issues stubbing ES modules:

```
const adminJS = await esmock('../adminFunctions.js', {
     '../adminFunctions.js': {
        mapCountAllTeams: false
     }
});
```

But I don't seem to be able to call `adminJS.mapCountAllTeams()` from within the test, it keeps returning undefined or the below error.  However when logging the actual functions output it is returning the correctly mocked value.

```
Promise {
  <rejected> TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
      at Function.values (<anonymous>)
      at Module.mapCountAllTeams (file:///C:/functions/adminFunctions.js?esmk=1?esmk=1:285:29)
      at Context.<anonymous> (file:///C:/functions/test/fklProdAdmin.test.js:103:36)
```

what is the best practice to be able to use esmock with calledOnce?

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example